# Closing Excel from Applescript without generating errors

Tags: excel, applescript

I have an Applescript that is designed to convert .xlsx files into .csv format, but it's having problems closing Excel after it's done processing, such that the next time Excel opens it gives the error message "excel saved changes to the file before the application quit unexpectedly".  If I run the Applescript twice in a row, this error message causes the second execution to crash.  Is there a way to either: close Excel more gently, so that it doesn't register the error; or tell Applescript to ignore the error and proceed with the rest of the program?

For reference, here is a simple Applescript that has the same problem (replace "etc.xlsx" with a path to some .xlsx file):

```
set fullpath to alias POSIX file "etc.xlsx" as text

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open fullpath as text
    close active workbook
    quit
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error you describe. You have some confusing file path stuff going on. Maybe that's your problem. To get the string path to a file use the following code and put the result path in for your fullpath variable.

```
(choose file) as text
```

Then here's the code to work with it.

```
set fullpath to "some:path:test.xlsx"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file fullpath
    close active workbook
    quit
end tell
```

It works without error.